# Send Image/video from raspberry pi to mobile

Tags: android, python, firebase, raspberry-pi, google-cloud-platform

I need to send image/video from raspberry pi based on the user preference when a sensor gets activated. I am planning to use Firebase for sending data in real-time, since the videos may be of large size I read its better to use google bucket with firebase.

I tried to upload an image in google bucket, but I am not able to figure out, what to do next. Do I need to put the public URL of the uploaded file in the Firebase and trigger an event in the mobile device?.

OR **am I making things complex?**